# Calling non-async methods

Tags: c#, async-await

Have a class library that makes use of a DbContext to return results from sql.
If I want to build a

Class library method that might take a few seconds. This class is injected into an asp.net core webapp in its Startup

```
class Util
{

    public string DoStuff(string colorVal) {

        string ourValue = (from a in ctx.BigTable where a.color == colorVal select a.DoneFlag).FirstOrDefault();

        return ourValue;

    }
}
```

Do I need to make this method async also if I intend to use it from code like this

```
Web project

        Util o;

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            var item = await GetMatchingColorAsync();
            return View(item);
        }

        private Task<string> GetMatchingColorAsync()
        {
            string matchingColor = o.DoStuff("red");            
            return Task.FromResult(matchingColor);
        }
```

Comment: You might as well, thats to say, if you are already using the async and await pattern, then it makes sense to keep using it

Comment: I was reading back over various sources about the use of async and await where it suggests starting at the lowest level of the callstack in your codebase to refactor to use async methods.  However, the problem is that by doing so I would have to modify a ton of other code that also depends on methods in this class library.  What is the impact of NOT making Util.DoStuff async?

Comment: The impact is probably nothing if your site is only for test purposes, or low usage. However you will lose scalability and you are stuck with sync methods everywhere.

Comment: you've probably noticed already, but most frameworks define both.  Just create the Task returning methods (duplicating the code) and use them for async await functions and operations.  Leave the synchronous methods so you don't impact the rest of your codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally yes. You could even use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` while you're at it (depending on what your underlying data source is):

```
public async Task<string> DoStuff(string colorVal) {

    string ourValue = await (from a in ctx.BigTable where a.color == colorVal select a.DoneFlag).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var someColor = await GetMatchingColorAsync();

    return ourValue;

}
```

Microsoft has a series of articles about [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) that are quite well written. They're worth the read.

If you *absolutely* can't change the calling methods, then you could just synchronously wait:

```
public string DoStuff(string colorVal) {

    string ourValue = (from a in ctx.BigTable where a.color == colorVal select a.DoneFlag).FirstOrDefault();

    var someColor = GetMatchingColorAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    return ourValue;

}
```

Easy right? Except it blocks the thread (you lose the benefit of the asynchronous methods) and you risk deadlocking, as explained in this article: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

That's Bad™

Comment: That makes sense because the whole idea is to return a task back up the stack with a task so the thread can move on. If it has to wait on this result, then the thread is blocked, correct?

Comment: no `await` in your example.  Also, you should consider that the lambda linq expression there is deferred execution on a dbcontext.  This wasn't a question that omits that consideration, and you aren't going to find it covered in that reference link.

Comment: actually.. forget the lambda linq expression consideration.. it's more relevant to the merit of a design pattern for utility functions than it is to this answer.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Thanks! I guess I wrote the answer too fast. I added the awaits. That's kind of important.

Comment: @bitshift Correct!